# Using subdirectories with quarto and RStudio

Tags: r, bookdown, quarto

Please consider the following.

I like to structure my R projects with different subdirectories. Using `bookdown` or `quarto` seems to make this quite difficult since both like to have their source files (.Rmd or .qmd) in the project directory. I was hoping that this will get easier with `quarto` but this does not seem the case, although it should be possible according to [this post](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2022-04-we-dont-talk-about-quarto/#what-youll-like).

---

**Problem description (replicable example)**

Start a new quarto book project in RStudio: File > New Project > New Directory > Quarto Book.

This will create several `.qmd` files in the R project directory. Now create new subdirectories. Starting from the R project directory: scripts/qmd.

If we put all `.qmd` files from the R project directory into scripts/qmd, we also need adapt their path in the `_quarto.yml` (e.g., from `index.qmd` to / `scripts/qmd/index.qmd`).

After doing so and pressing the Render button, we receive the `ERROR: Book contents must include a home page (e.g. index.md)`.

Putting only the `index.qmd` file back into the R Project directory (and adapt the `_quarto.yml`), the book can be rendered.

---

**Question**

- How can we put all `.qmd` files into a dedicated subdirectory?

---

**Edit (ignore below)**

Originally the below question was also asked but is now answered: quarto does not seem to have a "merge-knit" option like `bookdown` (see [here](https://yihui.org/en/2022/04/quarto-r-markdown/)). This unfortunately makes quarto useless for my use case.

- If this is not possible, how can we make sure that object created in the R project directory are accessible for the `.qmd` files in the subdirectories? (setting `execute-dir: project`  as suggested [here](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/code-execution.html#working-dir) did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your purpose is just a specific personal preference for file organization.

You can have a large portion of your content in subdirectories (and that's my understanding of what [Alison's blog post](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2022-04-we-dont-talk-about-quarto/) refers to), but you still need to have your `index.qmd` in the root. For example, you can have a subdirectory for projects, another one for posts, another one for tutorials, like Alison does.

In any case, one way of achieving what **you** want is by using [pre- and post-render scripts](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/scripts.html#pre-and-post-render).

You could move all the files from the scripts/qmd directory before rendering and then move them all back afterwards.

```
  pre-render: mv scripts/qmd/*.qmd .
  post-render: mv *.qmd scripts/qmd
```

Incidentally, that doesn't match my own personal preference ;-)

Comment: Does anyone know how robust this solution is if the render command fails? I would assume that there are cases where the post-render is not performed after the quarto command crashes, thereby making the next attempt to render invalid because the files are in the wrong place. For this reason, it doesn't seem like a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Lucas A. Meyer, I tested the pre-render and post render options you suggested above, however, it throws an error after moving the file from my subdirectory to the project root:
`ERROR: NotFound: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)`

Then, it fails to render the file and move it back to the original subdirectory location.

I then set `execute-dir: project` in my .yml file thinking it was trying to execute in the wrong folder, but it did not change anything.

P.S. I would have added as a comment, but my reputation is not high enough, yet. :(

UPDATE1:
I thinking I found a workaround for the time being. I've include the following project options beneath the `project:` header:

> `output-dir: subdir1/subdir2` Moves the html file, only.
> `post-render: xcopy *_files subdir1/subdir2 /E` Copies the supporting files over.

The `mv` shell command can't be used for directories or you get the Directory Not Empty error.`

Comment: Did you ask in the Quarto Q&A at https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions? The answers from developers and the community there are quick.

Comment: I haven't yet. I gave up on this issue for a while ago. I will come back to it shortly thanks to this reminder.