# Saving HTML files of Quarto website ignoring the (nested) directory structure

Tags: html, yaml, rstudio, quarto

I have a Quarto project (using version `1.4.176`) and I use the following folder structure to organize my stuff:

```
my-project
├── _quarto.yml          # Quarto YAML
├── scripts              # My R code
│   ├── hi.R              
|   └── bye.R
├── qmds                 # All my Quarto files
│   ├── alex.qmd
│   ├── bob.qmd
|   └── carl.qmd
├── figures              # All my figures/plots
│   ├── me.svg              
│   └── you.svg
└── index.qmd
```

And when I render the website using `quarto::quarto_render()` within RStudio, I get the

```
my-project
├── _quarto.yml          # Quarto YAML
├── docs                 # Rendered HTML files
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── qmds
│   |   ├── alex.html
│   |   ├── bob.html
|   |   └── carl.html
|   ├── search.json
|   └── site_libs
|       └── ...
├── scripts              # My R code
│   ├── hi.R              
|   └── bye.R
├── qmds                 # All my Quarto files
│   ├── alex.qmd
│   ├── bob.qmd
|   └── carl.qmd
├── figures              # All my figures/plots
│   ├── me.svg              
│   └── you.svg
└── index.qmd
```

Due to this file structure, when browsing the website (on my PC, or GitHub), the HTML files built from the Quarto files are located at

- `me.github.io/my-project/index.html`
- `me.github.io/my-project/qmds/alex.html`
- `me.github.io/my-project/qmds/bob.html`
- `me.github.io/my-project/qmds/carl.html`

(On my PC, the addresses are `C:/Users/Documents/my-project/docs/index.html` and so on.)

However, I do not want the rendered pages of `alex`, `bob`, and `carl` to be nested under the `qmds/` directory, and instead want the following folder structure:

```
my-project
├── _quarto.yml          # Quarto YAML
├── docs                 # Rendered HTML files
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── qmds
│   ├── alex.html
│   ├── bob.html
|   ├── carl.html
|   ├── search.json
|   └── site_libs
|       └── ...
├── scripts              # My R code
│   ├── hi.R              
|   └── bye.R
├── qmds                 # All my Quarto files
│   ├── alex.qmd
│   ├── bob.qmd
|   └── carl.qmd
├── figures              # All my figures/plots
│   ├── me.svg              
│   └── you.svg
└── index.qmd
```

Such that I can find the HTMLs at the following addresses:

- `me.github.io/my-project/index.html`
- `me.github.io/my-project/alex.html`
- `me.github.io/my-project/bob.html`
- `me.github.io/my-project/carl.html`

Is there a neat solution to this issue, **without** moving all my `.qmd` files to the root directory of my project?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** A very similar question has been asked [a year and a half ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72977964) (for Quarto version `1.2` or earlier), but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72989451/) (that suggests using pre- and post-render scripts) doesn't seem to be robust.